# Friend comparison and relational operators in C++ class template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, friend

From Lippman et al C++Primer 5th edition, section 16.1.2:

```
//forward declarations needed for friend declarations in Blob
template <typename> class BlobPtr;
template <typename> class Blob;
template <typename T> bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&)

template <typename T> class Blob {
   friend class BlobPtr<T>;
   friend bool operator==<T>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
}
```

**First question**:  in the line

```
friend bool operator==<T>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
```

why is the `<T>` present after `==`?  Why not simply write

```
friend bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
```

I added the following code to define operator== and to instantiate the class template.  It successfully compiles and links:

```
template <typename T>
bool operator==(const Blob<T> &lhs, const Blob<T> &rhs) {return true;}

int main() {
    Blob<int> a, b;
    a == b;
}
```

If I remove the `<T>` following `operator==` in the friend declaration, I get a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "operator==(Blob<int> const&, Blob<int> const&)", referenced from: _main in partial_blob-3ccda9.o
```

Clearly the `<T>` following `operator==` is necessary, but why?

**Second question**: If I want to define the relational less than operator `<` for the same class, I would guess that I should follow the pattern that worked for `==`:

1) forward-declare the operator

2) declare the operator as a friend, inserting the additional `<T>` whose function I don't understand

3) define the operator out-of-class.

I therefore add the following code:

```
template <typename T> bool operator<(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
template <typename T> class Blob {
   //other members as before
   friend bool operator<<T>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
}
bool operator<(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&) {return true;}
int main() {
   //other statements as before
   a < b;
}
```

This produces a compilation error around `operator<<T>`, I think because the compiler interprets `<<` as the insertion operator.  But if I rewrite the friend declaration as

```
friend bool operator<(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
```

then I get a linker error similar to the earlier linker error with `==`:

```
"operator<(Blob<int> const&, Blob<int> const&)", referenced from: _main in partial_blob-a85d5d.o
```

How can I successfully define operator `<` for this class?

(Note:  the operators must be declared as friends because more fully-realized implementations rely on private variables.)

Comment: Remember that friend functions declared like that are not member functions, they are non-member functions and without the `<T>` the function is not complete. As for `operator<<T>` try adding a space between the operator name and the template like `operator< <T>`.

Comment: On the undefined reference and its cause and solution (as you already know); http://stackoverflow.com/a/35891188/3747990

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - Can you provide a reference to an introduction to this syntax?  I don't even know what it's called, so I'm having trouble looking it up.  Is it template specialization?  Explicit instantiation?  Web searches for these terms aren't producing helpful results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting my own answer, acknowledging Joachim Pileborg and songyuanyao for direction.

I have simplified the code to focus on Question 1 only. Pileborg and Holt correctly pointed out that overloading `<` merely requires a space to help the compiler parse.

```
template <typename> class Blob;
template <typename T> bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&); //line 2

template <typename T> class Blob {
   friend bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&); //line 5
};

template <typename T>
bool operator==(const Blob<T> &lhs, const Blob<T> &rhs) {return true;} //line 9

int main() {
    Blob<int> a, b; //line 12
    a == b; //line 13
}
```

This code produces an error at link time.  To understand why, we’ll look at relevant language from the standard.

From the C++14 Standard n4296, 14.5.4 (See bottom for summary of terminology used here).

> For a friend function declaration that is not a template declaration:
>
> (1.1) — if the name of the friend is a qualified or unqualified template-id, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template, otherwise,
>
> (1.2) — if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching non-template function is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to that function, otherwise,
>
> (1.3) — if the name of the friend is a qualified-id and a matching function template is found in the specified class or namespace, the friend declaration refers to the deduced specialization of that function template (14.8.2.6), otherwise,
>
> (1.4) — the name shall be an unqualified-id that declares (or redeclares) a non-template function.

Now we look at the friend declaration on line 5, determining what it refers to according to the four steps listed above.

(1.1) `==` is not a template-id; move on...

(1.2) `==` is not a qualified-id; move on...

(1.3) `==` is not a qualified-id; move on...

(1.4) therefore, `==` is an unqualified-id that declares (or redeclares) a non-template function.

According to section 7.3.3 of the standard, the friend `==` is declared in the innermost enclosing namespace -- in this case, the global namespace.

When we instantiate `Blob<int>` on line 12, the compiler generates source code by substituting `int` for all occurrences of `T` in class Blob.  The friend declaration in the compiler-generated code then reads:

```
friend bool operator==(const Blob<int>&, const Blob<int>&);
```

Thus we have declared a (non-template) overload of `operator==` in the global namespace, with parameters of type `const Blob<int>&`.

When `a == b` is called on line 12, the compiler begins the overload resolution process.  It first looks for any non-template overloads that match the argument types.  It finds a perfect match in the form of the `operator==` declared when `Blob<int>` was instantiated.  The linker then looks for the definition of `operator==` corresponding to the best-match declaration, but it finds none, because the `operator==(const Blob<int>&, const Blob<int>&)` was never actually defined!

The solution is to use a template-id (which is NOT a template declaration) as the name in the friend declaration:

```
friend bool operator== <>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&)
```

or

```
friend bool operator== <T>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&)
```

Both `operator== <>` and `operator== <T>` are template-id’s (see terminology below); the former has an implicit template parameter list deduced from the function parameter list, and the latter has an explicit template parameter list.

When `Blob<int>` is instantiated on line 12, the compiler generates the following code for the friend declaration:

```
friend bool operator== <>(const Blob<int>&, const Blob<int>&)
```

or

```
friend bool operator== <int>(const Blob<int>&, const Blob<int>&)
```

In either case, the name of the friend is an unqualified template-id, so by (1.1) above, the friend declaration refers to a specialization of a function template.  The compiler then finds then finds a best template match for the requested `<int>` specialization.  The only template it finds is the template declared in line 2 and defined in line 9, which it calls, as desired.

**Terminology**

qualified-id: an identifier with an attached scoping operator, e.g. `std::string` or `::i`

unqualified-id: an identifier without an attached scoping operator, e.g. `string` or `i`.

template-id: the following excerpt (From the C++14 Standard n4296, 14.2) summarizes the structure of template-id’s:

> simple-template-id:
>
> ```
>  template-name < template-argument-list (opt)>
> ```
>
> template-id:
>
> ```
>  simple-template-id
>
>  operator-function-id < template-argument-listopt >
>
>  literal-operator-id < template-argument-listopt>
> ```
>
> template-name:
>
> ```
>  identifier
> ```

So some template-id’s would include `Foo<T>` and `==<T>`.  (== is an operator-function-id).  Notice that, unlike in a template declaration, `template <>` is not included in a template-id expression.

Answer (score 3):

> why is the `<T>` present after `==`? Clearly the `<T>` following `operator==` is necessary, but why?

Because `operator==` in friend declaration refers to the function template, you have to specify it explicity. Otherwise a non-template function will be declared, but the definition of it can't be found later. It's not the same sceen as invoking (and instantiation) of function template.

Note `T` could be omitted but `<>` is still needed. Such as:

```
// refers to a full specialization of operator==
friend bool operator== <>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
```

Another candidate way is to **define** the operator inside the class declaration, which will be inline and could be declared as non-template function. Such as:

```
template <typename T> class Blob {
   ...
   friend bool operator==(const Blob&, const Blob&) { 
       return ...;
   }
}
```

> This produces a compilation error around `operator<<T>`

Yes as you said, it should be written as `friend bool operator< <T>(...)`, or `friend bool operator< <>(...)`, or see my suggestion about non-template function friend.

Answer (score 0):

> **First question:** in the line
>
> ```
> friend bool operator==<T>(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
> ```
>
> why is the `<T>` present after `==`? Why not simply write
>
> ```
> friend bool operator==(const Blob<T>&, const Blob<T>&);
> ```

If you remove the `<T>`, gcc gives a warning:

> warning: friend declaration '`bool operator==(const Blob< <template-parameter-1-1> >&, const Blob< <template-parameter-1-1> >&)`' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]

Your are making a non-templated function a friend of your class, so the compiler/linker will be looking for a non-templated function, in your case:

```
bool operator==(const Blob<int>&, const Blob<int>&);
```

...which does not exist, thus the linker cannot find it.

If you do not add `<T>` (or `<>` to the `friend` declaration), you have to define a function for each type, which is probably not what you want.

> **Second question:** If I want to define the relational less than operator < for the same class, I would guess that I should follow the pattern that worked for ==:

This is a simple problem with the way C++ code is parsed, you need to insert a space between `operator<` and `<<`. This is the same problem that existed prior to C++11 where you had to use `vector<vector<int> >` instead of `vector<vector<int>>` because of the `>>`.